# What object is returned by LinkedList.iterator()?

Tags: java, iterator

Consider these an object:

```
Iterator<String> j = LinkedList.iterator();
```

Looking at java docs, for LinkedList class there is no implementation of iterator method in LinkedList class, however, the implementation is in AbstractSequentialList class.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return listIterator();
```

listIterator() method is implemented in AbstractList class which is parent class for AbstractSequentialList and  to sum it up it returns an iterator object which does not use concept of nodes if I'm not mistaken.

```
   public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    return listIterator(0);
}
private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
    ListItr(int index) {
        cursor = index;
    }
```

But `listIterator(int index)` method IS implemented in LinkedList class and uses concept of nodes.

```
 public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}

private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Node<E> lastReturned;
    private Node<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;
```

so returning to j, is it an iterator from "root" class AbstractList or the implementation LinkedList class is used?

Comment: Well, you should have another look at the concept of polymorphism and method overriding. The base implementation of `iterator()` will call `listIterator()` which in turn calls `listIterator(0)`. So if that last method is overridden for `LinkedList` then calling `iterator()` on a `LinkedList` the overridden method will be called and thus a `LinkedList.ListItr` will be returned.

Comment: `ListItr implements ListIterator<E>` I will recommend `composition` over `inheritence`

Comment: @Thomas oh okay I get it now. I though the only way to override a method is using override annotation.

Comment: @HynekHrabík As an annotation `@Override` has no effect on how the JVM executes code. It wasn't even added until version six (which is the seventh version).

Comment: `@Override` is more of an information to the dev or compiler that a method is _meant_ to override (and as of Java 6 implement) a method. That way the compiler can complain if that annotation is present (or missing if enabled) on a method that doesn't actually override/implement anything. This helps the dev spot errors faster because a method might look like it overrides another but actually doesn't for various possible reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `iterator()` returns `listIterator()`, `listIterator()` returns `listIterator(0)`, and `listIterator(int index)` is overridden by `LinkedList`, `LinkedList`'s `iterator()` method returns an instance of `LinkedList$ListItr`.